# Upload a CSV file using AJAX in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, csv

I want to upload a CSV file using ajax query.

Template:

```html
<form id="attendance-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="upload-attendance" name="employee-attendance-file">
</form>
```

AJAX:

```js
$("#upload-attendance").change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // disables submit's default action
    var input = $("#upload-attendance")[0];
    var employeeAttendanceFile = new FormData();
    employeeAttendanceFile.append("attendance-file", $('#upload-attendance')[0].files[0]);
    console.log(employeeAttendanceFile);
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url "attendance:employee-attendance-upload" %}',
        type: 'POST',
        headers:{
            "X-CSRFToken": '{{ csrf_token }}'
        },
        data: {
            "employee_attendance_file": employeeAttendanceFile,
        },
    
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data); // converts string of json to object
        },
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        });
    });
```

After uploading a CSV file, when I `console.log` the file variable (`console.log(employeeAttendanceFile);`) nothing returns. When I fetch the ajax request from django view, it also returns `None` (`print(csv_file)`).

```py
# views.py
class ImportEmployeeAttendanceAJAX( View):
    def post(self, request):
        csv_file = request.FILES.get("employee_attendance_file")
        print(csv_file)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When uploading data via a FormData object you have to pass it directly

```
    data: employeeAttendanceFile,
```

Also, the name you set for the file in the upload has to match when you try to access it.

```
    csv_file = request.FILES.get("attendance-file")
```

Comment: Still same problem. csv_file returning None